# CakePHP: How do i show error or flash for ACL deny access instead of only forwarding

Tags: cakephp, permissions, acl

During development, when i try to access a page that has not been set as ACO or rights are denied, I just get forwarded to the previous page, where I was instead of getting error or at least a flash.

I can't figure out this way what went wrong. How do i set it so i get error messages and how to debug? debug is set to `2`?

10x

Answer (score 2):

use `echo $this->Session->flash('auth');` it is mentioned on 1.3 book. On 2.0 book look in the :

> Displaying auth related flash messages

of authentication page