# Simple ACL - Redirect user if they have incorrect permissions

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I followed this 'Simple ACL controlled Application' CakePHP tutorial at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

Everything works fine but the app has a quirk that I don't like.

In the example there are three roles: admin, manager and user. I'm logged in with an account that has a user role. When I click on a link that I don't have permission to access, I'm redirected to the current url so, in essence, nothing appears to be happening. I don't like this since it appears like the app is unresponsive.

How can I redirect the user to a 'Permission denied' page instead of redirecting to the referrer? I already created a new action in the `UsersController` named `permissionDenied` and the corresponding view. I also created the aco for the action and allow all groups to access it.

Comment: Normally this is handled by setting the flash message, which would then appear on your page to let the user know they didn't have privlidges to view the other page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. On your advice I found this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913532/cakephp-how-do-i-show-error-or-flash-for-acl-deny-access-instead-of-only-forwar) which told me how to show the flash message.

Comment: I might also suggest that ACL is 99% of the times overkill.  (I found out the hard way my making a few apps using it).  Now, we just use users and roles using Cakes AuthComponent.  MUCH easier than ACL imo.

Comment: So you would suggest adding a 'role' column to the users table and then using $this->Auth->user('role') in the beforeFilter() methods of controllers to decide who is allowed to access which resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing appears to be happening is because you don't show the flash message that the Acl component generates in your view (as already mentioned by Dave in the comments). You would have to add this to your layout or view:

```
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

That way the user will see whatever message you have set as `authError` in the properties of your `AuthComponent`.

Another way is to run the Acl check in the beforeFilter method of your AppController and redirect the user if the Acl check fails, like this:

```
/**
 * ACL Check (CakeError controller is exempt from this example,
 * so errors are always "allowed" to be shown).
 */
if (!is_null($this->Auth->User()) && $this->name != 'CakeError'
    && !$this->Acl->check(array(
        'model' => 'User',
        'foreign_key' => AuthComponent::user('id')),
        $this->name . '/' . $this->request->params['action']
)) {

    // Optionally log an ACL deny message in auth.log
    CakeLog::write('auth', 'ACL DENY: ' . AuthComponent::user('username') .
        ' tried to access ' . $this->name . '/' .
        $this->request->params['action'] . '.'
    );

    // Render the forbidden page instead of the current requested page
    echo $this->render('/Pages/forbidden');

    /**
     * Make sure we halt here, otherwise the forbidden message
     * is just shown above the content.
     */
    exit;
}
```

That way, the `app/View/Pages/forbidden.ctp` file will be rendered and the exit statement will stop the redirect from ever happening.

Comment: Sorry to dig up old comments, but instead of calling Acl-check etc, why don't you just use $this->Auth->isAuthorized() ?